# What are some known VPN servers which work well with iOS and OSX clients?

Tags: vpn, macosx, ios

I am looking for a **stable VPN server** which is known to work with **iOS and OSX clients**.

If possible, I prefer packages that are installable via: `sudo apt-get install XXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenVPN** can be installed through the Ubuntu repositories and even has a GUI client on Apple.

- [OpenVPN Installation Instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openvpn.html)
- [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/), OpenVPN GUI for OSX

OpenVPN *can* be installed like so:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

[image: Install via the software center]

It seems **GuizmOVPN** supports OpenVPN connections from iOS

> GuizmOVPN is an OpenVPN GUI for iPhone/iPad, designed to be easy to setup, configure and run.

---

Source: http://www.guizmovpn.com/

According to [this site](http://hmastuff.com/blog/?p=52), All OpenVPN connections require a jailbroken Apple Device.

> On iOS, you need to have a jailbroken device.

Here is a list of supported VPN connections with iOS: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1288

I'm really only familiar with OpenVPN on Ubuntu, so I'm not sure I can be of much more help.

Comment: +1 ty - I will try it out with OSX... ...from a quick google, it appears that iOS doesn't support OpenVPN yet?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @kfmfe04 See my edit for iOS

Comment: ty for looking that up 8^( requires jailbreak...

Comment: @kfmfe04 Edit again. Sorry, not much more I can do